# Error: "SQL compilation error: invalid value [aws_private_api_gateway] for parameter 'API_PROVIDER'"

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-api-gateway, user-defined-functions, vpc

So I have been trying to implement an external UDF for use in Snowflake through AWS API Gateway.  I'm running into an error that I have not seen documented anywhere online.  The error occurs when trying to create an api integration using api gateway with a private endpoint:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE API INTEGRATION LAMBDA_API
API_PROVIDER = aws_private_api_gateway
API_AWS_ROLE_ARN = 'arn:aws:iam::************:role/****'
[API_KEY = '****************************************']
API_ALLOWED_PREFIXES = ('https://*******.execute-api.us-****-*.amazonaws.com/******')
ENABLED = true;
```

I have tried providing the optional arguement API_KEY, but no luck with that either. I essentially followed the steps listed [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-creating-aws-planning.html#aws-management-console) (more specifically, [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-creating-aws-common-api-integration.html)) verbatim.

Has anyone encountered this error, or does anyone know where I might be able to learn more about this parameter?

The code does execute if I specify API_PROVIDER as 'aws_api_gateway', but our current architecture requires a vpc configuration.

EDIT 1 - The exact error (also in title):

```
SQL compilation error: invalid value [aws_private_api_gateway] for parameter 'API_PROVIDER'
```

EDIT 2 - We noticed that the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-api-integration.html) for altering the API integration mentions that an AWS role ARN is not required for aws_private_api_gateway, removing this from the creation statement did not solve the issue however.

Comment: Is your Snowflake account also configured to use Privatelink? I assume yes, but thought of asking to confirm.

Comment: @sergiu Yes, we have Privatelink configured.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error here and found in Snowflake's documentation that:

> The API_PROVIDER cannot be changed

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-api-integration#usage-notes